# XsltListViewWebPart when sorting retrieves all the data instead of from the Query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I've been trying out the XsltListViewWebPart for SharePoint Foundation 2013.  So far I have been able to display my list according the the CAML query defined.  Here is my acsx code below:

```
    <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="False" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" 
InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" 
EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="test" ViewContentTypeId="0x" Default="FALSE" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" 
DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="Alarms" FrameType="Default" 
SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="Bottom" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" 
AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" TitleUrl="" DetailLink="" 
HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" 
ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="webPart" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" 
__WebPartId="{D6AB9404-8361-4F26-9B27-8FA4A98F1234}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
<ParameterBindings>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(core,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,moreItemsParen)" />
</ParameterBindings>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<XmlDefinition>
    <View Name="" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="test" Url="" Level="1" 
        BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png" >
        <Query>
            <Where>
                <And>
                    <Geq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Time' />
                        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2008-09-29T00:00:00Z</Value>
                    </Geq>
                    <Leq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Time' />
                        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2008-09-29T10:00:00Z</Value>
                    </Leq>
                </And>
            </Where>
            <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Time' /></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="Time"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Phase"/>
        </ViewFields>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <Aggregations Value="Off"></Aggregations>
        <Toolbar Type="None"/>
    </View>
</XmlDefinition>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
    using (SPSite _site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString()))
            {
                using (SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList _list = _web.Lists["Test"];
                    this.webPart.ListId = _list.ID;
                    this.webPart.ListName = _list.ID.ToString();
                    this.webPart.ViewGuid = "{3A1B6299-528F-419C-97B4-DECF78381A37}";

                    StringBuilder _xml = new StringBuilder();
                    _xml.Append("<View Name='' MobileView='TRUE' Type='HTML' Hidden='TRUE' DisplayName='' Url='" + Page.Request.Url.ToString() + "' Level='1' BaseViewID='1' ContentTypeID='0x' ImageUrl='/_layouts/images/generic.png'>");
                    _xml.Append("<Query>" +
                                    "<Where>" +
                                        "<And>" +
                                            "<Geq>" +
                                                "<FieldRef Name='Time' />" +
                                                "<Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2008-09-29T00:00:00Z</Value>" +
                                            "</Geq>" +
                                            "<Leq>" +
                                                "<FieldRef Name='Time' />" +
                                                "<Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2008-09-29T10:00:00Z</Value>" +
                                            "</Leq>" +
                                        "</And>" +
                                    "</Where>" +
                                    "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Time' /></OrderBy>" +
                                "</Query>");
                    _xml.Append("<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Time'/><FieldRef Name='Phase'/></ViewFields>");
                    _xml.Append("<RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>30</RowLimit>");
                    _xml.Append("<Aggregations Value='Off'/>");
                    _xml.Append("<Toolbar Type='None'/></View>");
                    this.webPart.XmlDefinition = _xml.ToString();
                }
            }
```

But when I sort the Time or Phase column, it retrieves all the data regardless of the query.  Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Going a bit to my grey area here, but have you tried removing the View definition from CAML in code behind? Usually if you define a View, it will take column/sort/etc. definitions from that view instead of what you define in your CAML.

Comment: Yes, I have tried removing the CAML in my code behind but the behavior is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set HasOverrideSelectCommand property like that:

```
webPart.HasOverrideSelectCommand = true;
```